# Passing variable arguments to a bash function

Tags: bash

So I am trying to pass variable arguments to a bash function. Here is what my code looks like

```
function log_output(){

  args=("$@")

  for statement in ${args}
  do
    echo "${statement}"
  done
}
```

When I make the following call `log_output "hello bye"` I expect the function to print hello bye in one line. However currently its printing it in two different lines. Why is the string "hello bye" being treated as two arguments by the function? What am I doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

Comment: `for statement in "${args[@]}"`; `${args}` only expands to the first element in the array (and then, because it isn't correctly quoted, string-splits it on characters in IFS and expands each resulting word as a glob).

Comment: BTW, `function foo() {` is a hybrid of legacy-ksh and POSIX sh function definition syntax forms that isn't compatible with *either* legacy ksh *or* POSIX sh. Use either (worse) `function foo {` -- which is the legacy ksh form -- or (better) `foo() {` with no `function`, which is the POSIX-compliant form. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Also, consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing issues it identifies before asking questions here. In this specific case, it would have given you the warning SC2128, explained in detail [in this wiki page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2128).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Much appreciated!